# storage of address of variable in memory

Tags: compiler-construction

When I look at a load/store architecture where a variable in the register is stored in the memory under a certain address. How does the compiler know under which address the variable is stored in the memory to load it? He has to have a table somewhere. If so, where is the table stored?

Comment: compiler or operating system?

Comment: compiler generates an executable file from a program, operating system is responsible to execute it. as you double click on a exe file. However interpreters execute a program line by line.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What you mean by "where"? Do you mean "what is structure of the table"?

In general, a compiler at the stage of code-generation separately stores info about external static data, internal static data, function parameters, and local variables. Some of them has't the address at all, cause they are located in CPU registers. Some has address in the stack, i.e. offset of the stack's head. Static data has "normal" address, but external data hasn't until linking stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler generates a [symbol table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_table) where variables of a program are kept. the base index of this table is zero and addresses are relative to this base. (this table is part of an `exe` file).

When operating system executes the exe file, it loads the symbol table into memory then assign a new base address to it. (depending where it can find an empty place to load the file). Then all addresses are calculated relative to this new base address. Actually the base address is added to their address in the symbol table (usually data segment register keeps this base address)